# Querying post by ID always returning the latest post (WordPress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, while-loop

I'm trying to retrieve a **single post** by the ID. `Stories` is my custom post type and it currently has three posts:

1. Blog 1 (ID: 1)
2. Blog 2 (ID: 14)
3. Blog 3 (ID: 49)

I have a variable called `$story_one`. `$story_one` has the value of `14`.

I'm now trying to retrieve information from the post with the `ID` of 14, so I've done:

```html
<?php

$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'stories',
  'id'             => $story_one,
  'posts_per_page' => 1
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts() ) {
  while( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post(); 
    the_title();
  } 
  wp_reset_postdata();
}

?>
```

This returns **Blog 3**. Blog 3 is the newest post in `stories`. When I've specified it to pull content from the post with the ID of 14 (Blog 2), why is it. showing me content from the latest blog?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `WP_Query()`, you can use `get_post()`, like this:

```
<?php

  $post = get_post($story_one);

  if(!empty($post)):
    echo $post->post_title;
    echo get_field("field name", $story_one);
  endif;

?>
```

About getting only from `stories` post type. Every post type is stored in the same posts table, so they have to use different post IDs.

The second `parameter` of `get_field()` function is the post ID.

Comment: The `wp_get_single_post()`is a depreciated function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_single_post/

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. In the test I did it worked.. Anyway, edited the answer.

Comment: No worries. The only questions I have is: 1. How can I get it to only get posts from the `stories` post type? and 2. The reason I had a while loop running is so that I can extract that posts info. I.e. I had an ACF field and was running `$extract = get_field('extract');` would this still be possible via this appraoch?

Answer (score 0):

The `query_var` for post ID is `p` not `id`

```php
    $args = array(
      'post_type'      => 'stories',
      'p'              => $story_one,
      'posts_per_page' => 1
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $query->have_posts() ) {
      while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post(); 
        the_title();
      } 
      wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest continuing to use WP_Query. The issue is just one of the query parameters.

I would ad 'p', to yours $args variable...like this...

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'stories',
  'p'             => $story_one,
  'posts_per_page' => 1
);
```

And that should get you the result you're after.

Good luck!